# Cannot convert Gujarati PDF(unicode) to text

Tags: java, pdf, unicode, utf-8, pdfbox

I am trying to read a PDF file of Gujarat electoral roll ([sample file](http://erms.gujarat.gov.in/ceo-gujarat/download/ERoLL/N001/N0010001.pdf)). I need to extract all the information in a structured format. I am using pdfbox from Apache to extract text from the PDF file.

The problem that I am facing is that certain characters are getting lost in the conversion and there is a lot of noise in the converted text. Please find the converted file [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5xypg0s9MhZNnVoREFlVG41dUE/edit?usp=sharing).

The code

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.*;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
PDDocument pd;
BufferedWriter wr;
try {
    File input = new File("myPDF_manual.pdf");
    File output = new File("newPaperTestFile.txt"); // The text file where you are going to store the extracted data
    pd = PDDocument.load(input);
    PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(output)));
    stripper.writeText(pd, wr);
    if (pd != null) {
        pd.close();
        wr.close();
        System.out.println(" file processed.");
    }
 } catch (Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
        } 
     }
}
```

I also tried the code using getText() method of PDFTextStripper class but the result is same.

I also tried to convert the pdf to xml using pdftohtml command line utility for linux. But there also some of the information is still lost. The xml file can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5xypg0s9MhZYzk1c1FURFNwbW8/edit?usp=sharing)

Please suggest me **any** solution to solve this problem. Solution doesn't need to be Java specific.

Comment: Have you tried iText? iText is a mature java-based PDF reading and generating solution. I'm not vouching for it, but if things are not going the way you want, consider this an alternative suggestion.

Comment: At first glance you have given three sources which do not match, the PDF for "11/218", the text for "30/218", and the xml for "1/315". How should anyone now help with your *characters are getting lost* issues?

Comment: @mkl I gave those links to show the nature of the problem. The nature of the problem, according to me is being depicted by those file links. I will find the corresponding files and change the links.

Comment: @FilipeFedalto After your suggestion, I tried using iText but the problem is still not solved.

Comment: @IshanJain As the files don't correspond, I cannot compare to find the *certain characters* which *are getting lost in the conversion* to text or *the information lost* in the XMLs. As I cannot read Gujarati, I cannot spot anything missing from the context either. Furthermore you should explain what you expect.

Comment: @IshanJain Concerning your attempt to implement that using iText and your problems still not been solved... have you tried programming a `RenderListener` customized for your documents?